# IIS URL Rewrite - URL gets partially decoded in the rewrite process

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have an API service running that accepts various API calls with a long parameter string that works. I have recently created an IIS redirect site as a intermediary to support https where the API system only supports http calls. The https re-write process works fine. However I noticed that IIS URL rewrite process partially decode the URL before sending it to the API service where the service fails to decode the URL. API call details are as follows:

**Calling the API service directly(this works fine)**

Original URL:
http://10.0.0.119:8041/datasnap/rest/TTransactionsModule/GetTransactions/%22%5B%7B%22FilterTypeID%22%3A6001%2C%22NotOperator%22%3Afalse%2C%22SortOrder%22%3A0%2C%22StartGroup%22%3A0%2C%22EndGroup%22%3A0%2C%22Values%22%3A%5B%22SO%22%5D%2C%22OperatorType%22%3A%22operator_Equals%22%2C%22SortType%22%3A%22SortType_Ascending%22%2C%22LogicOp%22%3A%22LogicOp_And%22%2C%22IsValid%22%3A%22False%22%2C%22RefCount%22%3A%220%22%2C%22Changed%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%7B%22FilterTypeID%22%3A6003%2C%22StartGroup%22%3A1%2C%22EndGroup%22%3A1%2C%22AvailableOperators%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22NotOperator%22%3Afalse%2C%22OperatorType%22%3A%22operator_Between%22%2C%22Values%22%3A%5B%2213%2F05%2F2021%22%2C%2211%2F08%2F2021%22%5D%2C%22LogicOp%22%3A%22LogicOp_And%22%2C%22SortOrder%22%3A1%2C%22SortType%22%3A%22SortType_Descending%22%2C%22IsValid%22%3A%22False%22%2C%22RefCount%22%3A%220%22%7D%5D%22/1/1/false

Decoded URL (Please note that encoding needs to be done to send dates falling in the URL):

[http://10.0.0.119:8041/datasnap/rest/TTransactionsModule/GetTransactions/"[{"FilterTypeID":6001,"NotOperator":false,"SortOrder":0,"StartGroup":0,"EndGroup":0,"Values":["SO"],"OperatorType":"operator_Equals","SortType":"SortType_Ascending","LogicOp":"LogicOp_And","IsValid":"False","RefCount":"0","Changed":false},{"FilterTypeID":6003,"StartGroup":1,"EndGroup":1,"AvailableOperators":[],"NotOperator":false,"OperatorType":"operator_Between","Values":["13/05/2021","11/08/2021"],"LogicOp":"LogicOp_And","SortOrder":1,"SortType":"SortType_Descending","IsValid":"False","RefCount":"0"}]"/1/1/false](http://10.0.0.119:8041/datasnap/rest/TTransactionsModule/GetTransactions/%22%5B%7B%22FilterTypeID%22:6001,%22NotOperator%22:false,%22SortOrder%22:0,%22StartGroup%22:0,%22EndGroup%22:0,%22Values%22:%5B%22SO%22%5D,%22OperatorType%22:%22operator_Equals%22,%22SortType%22:%22SortType_Ascending%22,%22LogicOp%22:%22LogicOp_And%22,%22IsValid%22:%22False%22,%22RefCount%22:%220%22,%22Changed%22:false%7D,%7B%22FilterTypeID%22:6003,%22StartGroup%22:1,%22EndGroup%22:1,%22AvailableOperators%22:%5B%5D,%22NotOperator%22:false,%22OperatorType%22:%22operator_Between%22,%22Values%22:%5B%2213/05/2021%22,%2211/08/2021%22%5D,%22LogicOp%22:%22LogicOp_And%22,%22SortOrder%22:1,%22SortType%22:%22SortType_Descending%22,%22IsValid%22:%22False%22,%22RefCount%22:%220%22%7D%5D%22/1/1/false)

The parameter section that the API service receives:

%22%5B%7B%22FilterTypeID%22%3A6001%2C%22NotOperator%22%3Afalse%2C%22SortOrder%22%3A0%2C%22StartGroup%22%3A0%2C%22EndGroup%22%3A0%2C%22Values%22%3A%5B%22SO%22%5D%2C%22OperatorType%22%3A%22operator_Equals%22%2C%22SortType%22%3A%22SortType_Ascending%22%2C%22LogicOp%22%3A%22LogicOp_And%22%2C%22IsValid%22%3A%22False%22%2C%22RefCount%22%3A%220%22%2C%22Changed%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%7B%22FilterTypeID%22%3A6003%2C%22StartGroup%22%3A1%2C%22EndGroup%22%3A1%2C%22AvailableOperators%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22NotOperator%22%3Afalse%2C%22OperatorType%22%3A%22operator_Between%22%2C%22Values%22%3A%5B%2213%2F05%2F2021%22%2C%2211%2F08%2F2021%22%5D%2C%22LogicOp%22%3A%22LogicOp_And%22%2C%22SortOrder%22%3A1%2C%22SortType%22%3A%22SortType_Descending%22%2C%22IsValid%22%3A%22False%22%2C%22RefCount%22%3A%220%22%7D%5D%22

**Calling the API service via the IIS rewrite process:**

Original URL that gets passed to the ISS site (Exactly the same call other than the https and dns) :

https://10.0.0.119:9015/datasnap/rest/TTransactionsModule/GetTransactions/%22%5B%7B%22FilterTypeID%22%3A6001%2C%22NotOperator%22%3Afalse%2C%22SortOrder%22%3A0%2C%22StartGroup%22%3A0%2C%22EndGroup%22%3A0%2C%22Values%22%3A%5B%22SO%22%5D%2C%22OperatorType%22%3A%22operator_Equals%22%2C%22SortType%22%3A%22SortType_Ascending%22%2C%22LogicOp%22%3A%22LogicOp_And%22%2C%22IsValid%22%3A%22False%22%2C%22RefCount%22%3A%220%22%2C%22Changed%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%7B%22FilterTypeID%22%3A6003%2C%22StartGroup%22%3A1%2C%22EndGroup%22%3A1%2C%22AvailableOperators%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22NotOperator%22%3Afalse%2C%22OperatorType%22%3A%22operator_Between%22%2C%22Values%22%3A%5B%2213%2F05%2F2021%22%2C%2211%2F08%2F2021%22%5D%2C%22LogicOp%22%3A%22LogicOp_And%22%2C%22SortOrder%22%3A1%2C%22SortType%22%3A%22SortType_Descending%22%2C%22IsValid%22%3A%22False%22%2C%22RefCount%22%3A%220%22%7D%5D%22/1/1/false

The parameter section that the API service receives from the ISS rewrite process:

%22%5B%7B%22FilterTypeID%22:6001,%22NotOperator%22:false,%22SortOrder%22:0,%22StartGroup%22:0,%22EndGroup%22:0,%22Values%22:%5B%22SO%22%5D,%22OperatorType%22:%22operator_Equals%22,%22SortType%22:%22SortType_Ascending%22,%22LogicOp%22:%22LogicOp_And%22,%22IsValid%22:%22False%22,%22RefCount%22:%220%22,%22Changed%22:false%7D,%7B%22FilterTypeID%22:6003,%22StartGroup%22:1,%22EndGroup%22:1,%22AvailableOperators%22:%5B%5D,%22NotOperator%22:false,%22OperatorType%22:%22operator_Between%22,%22Values%22:%5B%2213/05/2021%22,%2211/08/2021%22%5D,%22LogicOp%22:%22LogicOp_And%22,%22SortOrder%22:1,%22SortType%22:%22SortType_Descending%22,%22IsValid%22:%22False%22,%22RefCount%22:%220%22%7D%5D%22

When the parameter sections compared in either case it is clear that the URL revived via the IIS rewrite process decoded some characters such as ":" and "," (Example: near 6001 in the parameter section)

Can someone help me to fix this problem. Need to set the IIS re-write process to pass the exact URL parameter list it received to the API service without any decoding or encoding.

My IIS re-write web.config file content is as follows (Note that need to set the maxRequestLength, maxUrlLength, maxQueryStringLength for long URLs and requestValidationMode="2.0" to support cirtan URL validations)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8041/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" maxUrlLength="2097151" maxQueryStringLength="2097151" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

In iis there is a feature flag, useOriginalURLEncoding that allows you to turn off this non-compliant URL Encoding when set to true.

To set the flag to go `IIS Manager`, then select `Configuration Editor` and go to the section `system.webServer/rewrite/rules`, where you will find the `useOriginalURLEncoding` flag, set the flag to false, and URL Rewrite will no longer encode the URL.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have set the useOriginalURLEncoding to false. I have even restarted the server to make sure. But still I have the same problem.

Comment: I suggest you open a [support ticket](https://support.microsoft.com/) for this, microsoft engineers will help find the root cause.